# PHP PDOException: could not find driver but driver is installed?

Tags: php, pdo, sqlsrv

I'm running PHP 7.1 on an IIS 10.0 server and trying to connect to a MSSQL database.

Trying to instantiate a connection like this:

```
$dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=#server#;Database=#dbname#", "#username#", "#passwd#");
```

Gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\projects\test.php:6 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\projects\test.php(6): PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=...', '#username', '#pwd...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\projects\test.php on line 6

However, `sqlsrv` is activated in my `php.ini`:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll
```

It's uncommented, and it's the right `php.ini` (already checked with `phpinfo()`). Restarting the server also didn't do anything.

I really don't understand why this is happening when the driver is obviously installed :/

What makes it extra weird is that I have another application running on the same server that also connects to a MSSQL database and it works with no problems, it had an automatic installer though so I didn't have to configure anything myself. It also connects to a local db and right now I'm trying to connect to a remote one if that makes a difference.

Comment: are you running one via the apache web server and another via cli? sometimes they end up retrieving different php.ini files...

Comment: @Jeff nope, both via the web server, and as I said I checked the php.ini file with phpinfo().

Comment: There's also typically a PDO specific driver, i'm not sure with regards to the sqlsvr but for instance on mysql you must enable:
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
(note the pdo prefix before the driver name)

Comment: Found a php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll file in the extensions, added that to php.ini, restarted the server, still same error :(

Comment: Now I would check to ensure the dll is actually present in the extensions folder. Can't recall where that is though, but Google knows.

Comment: What is output from <?echo phpinfo()?>? Is there section about pdo_sqlsrv?